Invalid version number in '-target arm64-apple-ios9999'
Xcode automatically updated yesterday and now I can't build my app anymore.

Xcode version is 15.4
clang version is 15.0.0

And when I try to run/build the app this is the error I get:

/clang:1:1 invalid version number in '-target arm64-apple-ios9999'

That's it. The weirdest part is the 9999 number there, I can't find it anywhere in the code, must be something Xcode is setting.
I tried running softwareupdate --all --install --force without success (it ended up updating my MacOS, but still same error).
Installing and running from Xcode 15.3 works just fine.

FWIW we have someone on our team currently seeing this as well. Nothing changed from Xcode 15.3 to 15.4 upgrade. We'll let you know if/how we resolve.

This appears to be a bug with the Sentry dependency.
Logged here: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cocoa/issues/3980

I was on Sentry 8.24.0; upgrading to 8.26.0 fixed it for me.

Is this still working for you? I've tried 8.28, and 8.26, and have wasted hours on this issue today!
@Kyle Beard Assuming from your message above that you're at Sentry - any news on this - it's been a month and is caused by the Sentry SDK no matter whether it was an Xcode change that triggered it or not!

You might have to clear derived data as well after updating Sentry.
